# What happens to the pthread when it exits the function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Say I use `pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*fun) (void *), void *arg)` in a `while` loop, what happens to the thread(s) once it finishes function `fun()`, does it also fall in to the loop with the main thread if I call  `int pthread_detach(pthread_t thread)` or does only the main thread stay in the loop?

Example:

```
pthread_t t[NTHREADS];

int i = -1;
while(1){

  //do something
  ++i;

  pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, fun, (void *)i);
  pthread_detach(t[i]);

  //main thread goes on, created one detaches when finished

}
```

What I want to do is a multi client server where each thread serves it's own client, there is `NTHREADS` and when certain thread finishes `fun()` or rather serving it's client, then the slot in `t[]` opens up and another thread can be created(other client can connect) if it was full before.

Comment: You'll need a mutex to protect `t`, so that the threads can safely set `t[i]` to an "unused" value before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification says that returning from a thread function is equivalent to calling `pthread_exit`, with the thread function's return value becoming available to `pthread_join` (provided you didn't detach the thread).

Typically, this is implemented by having `pthread_create` create a thread that starts executing a fixed (libc) "thread entry function". This entry function calls your function, then calls `pthread_exit` (after any relevant cleanup is done).

Answer (score 1):

A pthread returning from its start function is equivalent to that thread calling `pthread_exit`. If the thread is detached, it ceases to exist.